# arrayadapter for spinner keep error

Tags: java, android

I want to make spinner inside my Google Map class so i can change the view of googlemaps like HYBRID, SATELLITE so on.. I make a this spinner on fragment inside of fragment.
when i declare arrayaddapter it keep show "Unfortunately, --- has stopped"

```
public class GMaps extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_map, null, false);

    sview = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    // ..
```

I think it is because the parameter `context = this.getActivity()`... I have try this.getView(), getActivity(), v.getContext, nothing works.

Comment: Read the error log - it will contain an exception stack trace with useful information, including line on which the exception was raised. Also consider attaching a debugger and breaking on thrown exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//your spinner is in popup_map.xml so you need to do

```
sview = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

instead of `getActivity()` you need to use `View v`

```
sview = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should change this

```
sview = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

to

```
sview = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

it's becoz your `Spinner view` belong to you `inflated layout view`.

then try to set adapter like:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
 dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 sview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: thanx...sometimes i still confused about the context like 'this', 'this.getActivity()', or so on...